# Product Configuration Wizard Fails Step 2 of 9

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard

I recently installed a SharePoint 2010 Server Language Pack from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3411). The install went smoothly and the language pack installed successfully. After completing the installation, the installation wizard prompted me to run the SharePoint 2010 Product Configuration Wizard.

I ran the SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard and it started to execute. There was a brief pause on *Step 2 of 9 - Initializing the Upgrade Sequence*. Then the wizard failed with the following message:

> Failed to initialize the upgrade sequence.
>
> An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. Additional exception information: Exception of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException" was thrown.

I analyzed the log file provided and found the following exception:

> Task upgradebootstrap has failed with an unknown exception.

From the event viewer I found a few more details:

> Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence. An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. Additional exception information: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown. Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.BootStrap(Guid sessionId, SPUpgradeOperationFlags flags) at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.Run() at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

I've browsed the web and found several articles on the issue. However, none of the solutions seem to work. I have even downloaded the [Microsoft Chart Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=122517) and installed them as one post recommended but to no avail. The configuration wizard still fails.

Unfortunately, I'm at the end of the my knowledge rope when it comes to SharePoint. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:**

After some futher debugging, I found the following message above the detailed Exception message:

> 05/29/2014 10:51:28  12  ERR    Task upgradebootstrap has failed
>
> 05/29/2014 10:51:28  12  INF    friendlyMessage for task upgradebootstrap is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
>
> 05/29/2014 10:51:28  1  INF    Resource retrieved id upgradeBootstrapTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel is Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence.
>
> 05/29/2014 10:51:28  1  INF    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
>
> 05/29/2014 10:51:28  1  INF    Updating the task label below the progress bar Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence.

It doesn't appear to be any more helpful than the previous message though.

**EDIT 2: Upgrade Log**

> [PSCONFIG] [SPDelegateManager] [INFO] [5/29/2014 12:03:13 PM]: No context object
> [PSCONFIG] [SPDelegateManager] [ERROR] [5/29/2014 12:03:13 PM]: Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: what is the sharepoint Build level? are you SharePoint is also on SP2 level?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Thank you for your feedback. My apologies for not responding sooner. I was pulled away on a separate project. Where exactly do I find my _Build Level_? I found the Configuration Database Version in Central Admin. It's version: 14.0.6126.5000. Is that my _Build Level_? I also found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687355) article as a reference from the number I provided above. Don't know if this helps or not.

Comment: so your sharepoint is not on the SP2 level(You are August 2012 Level), while you installed the Language packs with SP2. i think best bet is uninstall the language pack, then install SP2 for SharePoint then install LP as well.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Ok. I'll try running that now and I'll come back and update you in a few.

Comment: another solution is slipstream SP1 LPs...check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ronalg/archive/2011/07/11/slipstream-sharepoint-2010-sp1-and-language-packs-w-sp1-into-rtm.aspx

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Ok. I uninstalled the language pack and downloaded service pack SP2. I installed the Service Pack and ran the configuration wizard again. Again, it failed. The version number in Central Admin remains the same. Any ideas?

Comment: did you install SP2 for sharepoint server?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I installed [_Service Pack 2 for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 (KB2687453) 64-Bit Edition_](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39672). Is this correct?

Comment: that's correct, reboot the server and then try to run config wizard

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Ok. Will do. Will update shortly.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE No such luck. Still errored out.

Comment: ok, run this one PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force in sharepoint powershell

Comment: how many servers you have in farm?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE 1 server. Ran the command. Same error message occurred. _"Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException"_ on step 2 Initiating the upgrade sequence...

Comment: can you send the complete upgrade log, to check the squence

Comment: do you have anyother product installed on the server i.e office ?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I've updated the question with a snippet of the upgrade log that looked relevant. Office 2013 is installed on the server as well.

Comment: office 2013 is your problem. the assembly mentioned is info path which having conflict with sharepoint. i recommend uninstall the office and then try again.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Ok. I'll give this a while and update you when I'm finished. Thank you so much for your assistance. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Uninstalling Infopath was indeed the trick. I ran into a few other problems along the way, but I got them solved. The configuration wizard now runs completely and successfully. Thanks a bunch. Post your comment to remove Infopath as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: good to know, your issue fixed, i just added the anwser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error

> Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies.

**office 2013** is your problem. the assembly mentioned is info path which having conflict with sharepoint. **i recommend uninstall the office and then try again**.

Answer (score 2):

Few things to check here:

1. Ensure you have downloaded the language pack for each service pack.  For instance, if you have Service Pack 2 installed, download the language pack for the RTM version (which you linked), Service Pack 1, and Service Pack 2.
2. Try turning off UAC (user account control) in the Users section of the Control Panel in Windows.  Reboot and then try again.  Sometimes UAC messes up PSConfig for 2010.
3. There should be a log file linked on the fail screen.  If the above doesn't work, open that log file to look for warnings and errors.  That will give us a better indication of what to look for.

**EDIT**

It looks like you have the InfoPath client installed (part of Office).  When you install InfoPath on a SharePoint server, the assemblies between the two conflict.  Remove InfoPath (or Office all-together) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I'll try the above steps and sift through that error log. I'll let you know what I find and post any additional information that I discover.

Comment: No more RTM language Packs available, Now you get Language with SP2, link also mentioned sp2.

Comment: @JohnChapman Thank you again for the fast reply. I apologize I wasn't able to jump back on this sooner. I was pulled away on a separate project. I've updated my question with some more events from the Event log. I verified that the language packs were for SP2 (point 1). I also disabled UAC, restarted the server and tried the wizard again (point 2) still with no luck. Any ideas with the new information posted?

Comment: In the new log there exist a Version Mirakel. It will tried to find ver 14 from infopath Server that is ok... But then it will try to fing infopath ver 15 Thais a Office 2013 Version. Is it possible that you have installed Office 2013 on the Server? Mayer it could be makes some erfrorst i think.

Comment: Updated my answer, remove Office/InfoPath from the SharePoint server.

Comment: @JohnChapman Thanks so much for your help. It's greatly appreciated. This indeed did solve the problem. Wish I could +1000000. Anyway, +1 Great Solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this error by removing InfoPath from the GAC.

This link,
https://vinayjayaram.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/office-2013-breaks-sharepoint-2010-an-exception-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spupgradeexception-was-thrown/, which references this article, 
https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/mafsarkhan/archive/2013/08/05/office-2013-breaks-sharepoint-2010-an-exception-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spupgradeexception-was-thrown, recommended deleting the InfoPath DLLs from the GAC.

Rather than deleting the folders, I moved them to a new folder outside the GAC.

Delete the following folders from `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL`. (Alternatively, move them outside the GAC.)

- Policy.14.0.Microsoft.Office.InfoPath
- Policy.14.0.Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Client.Internal.Host
- Policy.14.0.Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.FormControl

Then re-run the Configuration wizard